# password validation for page not working

Tags: php, arrays, validation, passwords

the login.php form and password.php is working but the validation for entering a site is not

code for "passwords.php"

```
<?php 
$USERS["username1"] = "password1"; 
$USERS["username2"] = "password2"; 
$USERS["username3"] = "password3"; 

function check_logged(){ 
     global $_SESSION, $USERS; 
     if (!array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) { 
          header("Location: login.php"); 
     }; 
}; 
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include("passwords.php"); 
if ($_POST["ac"]=="log") { /// do after login form is submitted  
     if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) { /// check if submitted 

          $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"]; 
     } else { 
          echo 'Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.'; 
     }; 
}; 
if (array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) { //// check if user is logged or not  
     echo "You are logged in."; //// if user is logged show a message  
} else { //// if not logged show login form 
     echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> '; 
     echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" />'; 
     echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" />'; 
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
     echo '</form>'; 
}; 
?>
```

i cant make this part work

validation for page:

```
<?php 
session_start(); /// initialize session 
include("passwords.php"); 
check_logged(); /// function checks if visitor is logged. 
?>
```

page code goes here

what am i doing wrong? the validation does not check if the user is logged in or not. 
it just proceeds to the page.

Comment: Try to avoid using global variables...

Comment: I assume the `password.php` is just a typo and it is really called `passwords.php`? As it is a necessary file, I would recommend `require` instead of `include`.

Comment: When you look at the source of a page that includes validation, is there something included at the top, like a PHP warning? That would prevent your `header` call from working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You should add exit; after setting the redirection header so the rest of the page doesn't get processed.

```
 if (!array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) { 
      header("Location: login.php"); 
      exit;
 };
```

Also, did you try closing the browser to clear all the session data and see if you are still logged in?